# Calculate the X and Y (top and left) values for the shape after setting the rotation for it

Tags: openxml

Need help in adjusting the top and left of the shape when rotation value is set. 
For Ex :

```
<p:spPr bwMode="auto">
           <a:xfrm rot="5400000">
                <a:off x="2443049" y="-1042472" />
                <a:ext cx="304800" cy="4419600" />
            </a:xfrm>
            <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                <a:avLst />
            </a:prstGeom>
            <a:ln>
                <a:headEnd />
                <a:tailEnd />
            </a:ln>
```

I have the above data. I have calculated the rotation angle accordingly. Now when creating the shape and displaying it in an html format, need to adjust the top and left (off x="2443049" y="-1042472") values to align it properly. Kindly provide a solution to calculate proper top and left values to set.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [how to calculate the rotation value for the MS Office Powerpoint Shapes from the xml data given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12085076/how-to-calculate-the-rotation-value-for-the-ms-office-powerpoint-shapes-from-the), their is no need to change the left and top of a shape - if it is rotated or not-rotated, the shape will have the same left/top as it is an in-place rotation (it rotates on the Center X/Y).

If you're looking for how to translate EMU to points/pixels so that it can be converted to a different format such as HTML, use **EMU/12700**. So in this case `<a:off x="2443049" y="-1042472" />` would be `left="192.37" top="-82.08"` and `<a:ext cx="304800" cy="4419600" />` would be `width=24 height=348`.